# Any windows API or any library to notify the changes in the Drive (especially USB drives)?

Tags: winapi, notifications, usb

I am currently doing POC for logging the files which are copied into / delete in / renamed in the drive.

It's kind of like USB file auditing.

Currently I have done with the help of ReadDirectoryChangesW ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(VS.85).aspx)) in c++ and also done with FileSystemWatcher ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)) in c#.net .

But according to me, it was not right thing what I am doing to track the file changes in the drive.

==> Is there any WinAPI or third party library which will notify the copy changes or any other actions like deleting file, renaming file, modifying file in the USB devices or for drives.

==> Is there any API or functions which was provided from Windows 8 ?

==> Is it possible to monitor the drive for read / write / delete / rename / modify like events ?

Please suggest me if any method to track the changes in the drive or USB devices .

Kindly revert back for any clarifications.

Thanks,

Thiyagu

Comment: How reliable do you want that to be? If super reliable, you need a minifilter.

Comment: `ReadDirectoryChangesW` - work for some folder. if you select root folder on volume - you got notify about all changes on volume - and this volume on USB or not USB drive - absolute not important\

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to monitor the drive for read / write / delete / rename / modify like events ?

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/windows/desktop/aa364391(v=vs.85).aspx, it is possible to use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to monitor file creation, deletion, modification or rename.